# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom, promises

I need to render some values in the screen based in boolean variable (isLaborOrPartsLabor), and i'm setting this one in a method inside the renderedCallback(), basically, when this one it's true i'm hiding a button that will be used to render the same data. This works fine in the scenario where the button needs to be triggered (I assume it's because i don't call the handleNew() function in the callback in this one), but for the scenario where the boolean variable is false, and the data needs to be rendered when the screen loads, i'm calling the function to set parameters in callback, and is throwing me this error:[image]

I don't know another way to render the data i need in the screen without using the renderedCallback, so, if anyone could help me with this one, i would appreciate!

**Code:**

lwc.html

```
 <template>
        <!-- <lightning-card> -->
        <div class="slds-p-around_xxx-small">
            <template if:true={editData}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:note" size="small" class="slds-m-top_xx-small slds-m-left_medium"></lightning-icon>
                        <h class="slds-text-title_bold slds-p-left_small slds-p-top_medium" style="font-size: medium">{titleName1}</h>
            </template>
            <template if:true={onLoad}>
                <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium" variant="brand"></lightning-spinner>
            </template>
            <template if:false={onLoad}>
                <template if:false={hasInstructions}>
                    <template if:false={editData}>
                        <template if:false={isLaborOrPartsLabor}>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                                    <div class="slds-p-top_xx-small">
                                        <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:note" size="small" class="slds-m-top_xx-small slds-m-left_medium"></lightning-icon>
                                        <lightning-formatted-text class="slds-p-left_small" style="font-size: medium" value="Please add any instructions if required for this dispatch."></lightning-formatted-text>
                                        <lightning-button class="slds-p-horizontal_x-small slds-p-bottom_xx-small slds-float_right" variant="brand" label="Add Instructions" title="Primary action" onclick={handleNew} disabled={disableActions}></lightning-button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </template>   
                    </template>
                </template>
                <template if:false={editData}>
                    <template if:true={hasInstructions}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:note" size="small" class="slds-m-top_xx-small slds-m-left_medium"></lightning-icon>
                            <h class="slds-text-title_bold  slds-p-left_small slds-p-top_medium" style="font-size: medium">{titleName1}</h>
                                <lightning-button class="slds-float_right slds-p-bottom_small" variant="Neutral" label="New" title="New"
                                    onclick={handleNew} disabled={disableActions}></lightning-button>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <lightning-datatable key-field="Name" data={parentScope.woInstructions} columns={usercolumns} onrowaction={handleRowActions} max-row-selection="1">
                        </lightning-datatable>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <template if:true={editData}>
                    <div class=" slds-p-left_small slds-p-right_small slds-p-bottom_small">
                    </div>
                    <div class=" slds-p-left_small slds-p-right_small slds-p-bottom_small">
                        <div>
                            <lightning-formatted-text>Edit </lightning-formatted-text>
                            <lightning-dual-listbox name="audience" label="Audience" source-label="Available" selected-label="Selected" options={audienceOptions.data.values} onchange={handleInstructionChange} value={audienceValue} min="1" required></lightning-dual-listbox>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-p-top_medium">
                                <div class="slds-col">
                                    <lightning-combobox name="visibility" label="Visibility" value={visibility} options={visibilityOptions.data.values} onchange={handleInstructionChange} required></lightning-combobox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-col">
                                    <lightning-combobox name="type" label="Type Of Instruction" value={type} options={typeOptions.data.values} onchange={handleInstructionChange}></lightning-combobox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-p-top_medium">
                                <div class="slds-col">
                                    <lightning-combobox name="template" label="Template Type" value={templatetype} options={options} onchange={handleTemplateChange} ></lightning-combobox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-p-top_medium ">
                                <div class="slds-p-around_xxx-small">
                                    <lightning-textarea class="textAreaBody" data-id="instruction" name="description" required value={description} label="Description" onchange={handleInstructionChange}></lightning-textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-p-top_small">
                            <lightning-button variant="Neutral" label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick={handleEdit} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                            <lightning-button variant="Brand" label="Save" title="Save" onclick={handleSave} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </template>
                
            </template>
            </div>
        <!-- </lightning-card> -->
    </template>
```

lwc.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import DispatchInstruction from '@salesforce/schema/DispatchInstruction__c';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import AUDIENCE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/DispatchInstruction__c.Audience__c';
import VISIBILITY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/DispatchInstruction__c.Visibility__c';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/DispatchInstruction__c.Type_of_Instruction__c';

export default class WorkOrderInstructionsLwc extends LightningElement {
    @api parentScope;
    @api recordId;
    @api workOrderData;
    @api loadSuccess;
    @track instructionsData;
    @track instructionarray = [];
    @track audienceValue = [];
    @track audience;
    @track visibility;
    @track type;
    @track description;
    @track editData = false;
    selectedInstruction = [];
    audienceOptions;
    visibilityOptions;
    typeOptions;
    @track hasInstructions =  false;
    @track NewData = false;
    @track disableActions = true;
    @track actions = [
        { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit' },
        { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' },
    ];
    @track usercolumns = [
        { label: 'Visibility', fieldName: 'Visibility__c', hideDefaultActions: true},
        { label: 'Audience', fieldName: 'Audience__c', hideDefaultActions: true},
        { label: 'Description', fieldName: 'Instruction__c', hideDefaultActions: true},
        {
            type: 'action',
            typeAttributes: { rowActions: this.actions },
        }
    
    ];
    @track isLaborOrPartsLabor = false;
    @track isFirstTime = true;
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: DispatchInstruction })
    dispatchInstructionObjectInfo;
    @wire(getPicklistValues,{ recordTypeId: '$dispatchInstructionObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: AUDIENCE_FIELD})
    audienceOptions;
    @wire(getPicklistValues,{ recordTypeId: '$dispatchInstructionObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: VISIBILITY_FIELD})
    visibilityOptions;
    @wire(getPicklistValues,{ recordTypeId: '$dispatchInstructionObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD})
    typeOptions;

    renderedCallback(){
        console.log('Inside Instruction renderedCallback :: parentScope ::' + JSON.stringify(this.parentScope));
        if(this.parentScope){
            this.disableActions = false;
            this.setDatafromParentScope();
            if(this.isFirstTime && this.isLaborOrPartsLabor){
                this.handleNew();
            }
        }else{
            this.disableActions = true;
        }
    }
setDatafromParentScope(){
        if(!this.editData && this.parentScope){
            this.instructionsData = this.parentScope.woInstructions;
            console.log('this.instructionsData::' + JSON.stringify(this.instructionsData));
            if(this.instructionsData.length > 0){
                this.hasInstructions =  true;                            
            }else{
                this.hasInstructions =  false;
            }
            if(this.workOrderData.Service_Type__c == 'Parts and Labor' || this.workOrderData.Service_Type__c == 'Labor Only'){
                this.isLaborOrPartsLabor = true;
            }
        }
    }

    setLocalParams(audience, visibility, type, description){
        this.audience = audience;
        this.audienceValue = [];
        let testaudience = [];
        if(this.audience?.includes(";")){
            testaudience = this.audience.split(";");
            this.audienceValue.push(...testaudience);
        }else{
            this.audienceValue.push(this.audience);
        }
        this.visibility = visibility;
        this.type = type;
        this.description = description;
    }

    handleNew(){ 
        this.handleEdit();
    }

    handleEdit(insItemSelected){
        console.log('this.editData:' + this.editData);
        if(this.editData){
            this.editData =  false;
            this.newData =  false;
            this.selectedInstruction = [];
            this.setLocalParams(null, null, null, null);
        }
        else if(!this.editData){
            this.editData =  true;
            if(insItemSelected){
                this.selectedInstruction = insItemSelected;
                this.setLocalParams(this.selectedInstruction.Audience__c, this.selectedInstruction.Visibility__c, this.selectedInstruction.Type_of_Instruction__c, this.selectedInstruction.Instruction__c);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(insItemSelected));
            }else{
                this.selectedInstruction = [];
                this.newData =  true;
                this.isFirstTime = false;
                if(this.isLaborOrPartsLabor){
                    this.setLocalParams('Field', 'Internal (Private)', 'Outbound', null);
                } else {
                    this.setLocalParams(null, 'Internal (Private)', 'Outbound', null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is being thrown because you didn't check if you actually had data yet. The first render cycle happens before any data is provisioned (it is still "undefined"), so you need to check if data exists first.

```
<div lwc:if={audienceOptions.data}>
  <lightning-formatted-text>Edit </lightning-formatted-text>
  <! -- rest of code -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , made the changes suggested and it worked!